# Unable to boot into Ubuntu after upgrading to 17.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I got a dual boot running on my Hp spectre: Windows 10 and Ubuntu
Before the installation of the recent update the partition or starting the system worked well. Nevertheless after the update I am now unable to boot back into linux, there is no menu anymore from which I can select which OS I'd like to use. Now it is just Windows 10 starting.

I have no clue so far how to fix this. If there is anyone who could help me, I'd be pretty grateful.

Comment: If your OSes are installed in UEFI mode just go to UEFI settings and make Ubuntu first priority boot again.

Comment: I tried that already, but there is no option anymore for my ubuntu partition.

Comment: If you just installed the notorious `Windows 10 Anniversary Update` then it may have wiped your linux partition. If you boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and start `gparted` do you still see an EXT4 partition?

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but I fixed it now. I just had to run boot-repair. I followed along the instructions of this video: https://youtu.be/i97y5Y2nChs